# Unix: How to Test Ip Address is resolved to name

Tags: networking, shell-script, dns

Unix: How to Test ip Address is resolved to name.

I need to check whether ip address can be resolved to name using DNS entry via shell script.

Code:

```
DNS_Lookup()
{
        LOOKUP=$(nslookup $1)
        FAIL_COUNT=$(echo $LOOKUP | grep "** server can't find " | wc -l);
        if [ $FAIL_COUNT -eq 1 ];then
            echo "Unable to resolve DNS for $1" 
        else
            echo "IP:$1 DNS Name:$(echo $LOOKUP | grep -v nameserver | cut -f 2 | grep name | cut -f 2 -d "=" | sed 's/ //')" 
            return 0
        fi
} 

DNS_Lookup 192.168.27.191
```

The above code is not working in all possible cases.
OS:CentOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getent` command with the `hosts` parameter like this:

```
getent hosts www.google.com
```

And count how many results this gets:

```
getent hosts www.google.com | wc -l
```

`getent` uses the Name Service Switch libraries to do various name lookups. With the second parameter you can define which kind of db you want to lookup. Check `man getent` for details.

Comment: Thanks will this command work in all OS (i.e) Unix ??

Comment: I'm not sure about -all- OS, but it works on Linux, FreeBSD and Solaris which already covers quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Showing two possible approaches which are portable.

```
#!/bin/sh

reverseDNS=$(host 8.8.8.8) 
if [ $? != 0 ]; then 
    printf '%s\n' "Reverse DNS [FAILED]"
else
    printf '%s\n' "Reverse DNS [OK]"
fi

###### nslookup ##########

nslookup_func(){

    nslookup=$(nslookup google.com)

    if [ "$nslookup" = ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "nslookup [FAILED]"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "nslookup [OK]"
    fi
}

nslookup_func
```

Comment: Thank you ... I have tried the first approach already in CentOS it returns the exit code always as 0. But in RHEL it should works fine.  For second approach there are lot of possible errors please see the link http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_HTML/MAN/MAN8/0537____.HTM     So that i am trying for alternative .....

Comment: That is the manpage of nslookup. I don't know what your alternative is or what you are referring to with the link.

Comment: I referring your if check "if [ "$nslookup" = ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" ];" which checks for only two errors but there are lot more errors can be shown .....

Comment: I referring your if check "if [ "$nslookup" = ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached" ];" which checks for only two errors but there are lot more errors can be shown .....